# Trouble reading from a text file

Tags: java

I need a program to read from a text file. The text file:

```
S 3
H 5
L 5
B 4 5
```

S, H, L, and B each refers to a certain shape (square, triangle, etc.) and the number after that is the Height and Width (if applicable). For example, "S 3" means a square with a height of 3:

```
* * * 
* * * 
* * *
```

So far I have this:

```
File dataFile = new File("textfile.txt");

            Scanner in;
            in = new Scanner (dataFile);

            int variable = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println(variable);
```

(I used the int "variable" to test it.) So, since "S" is not an integer, I cannot use

```
int variable = in.nextInt();
```

So, how can I have the program read it as a string and an integer immediately following?

Comment: Look at the other `Scanner` methods...

Comment: You can just read the whole thing as a string then look at the individual characters of that string.  Also, you can read them as `char`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `in.next()` to read the single character `String` and then convert it to a `char` by using `charAt(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that you can do involves `String.split`:

The basic idea is that you read in one line at a time using `in.nextLine()`, and use `split()` with `" "` as your delimiter. So, something like

```
String[] tokens = in.nextLine().split(" ");
```

In your example input, the idea is that if the first line was `"S 3"`, then `tokens` will be a `String` array of length 2 with elements `"S"` and `"3"`. More generally, the first element of the resulting array should be your letter, and the rest of the array should be the height and width parameters, which you can parse yourself to get the necessary information.